# Adding HTML to a WordPress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I tried to add a CTA to a WordPress site. I placed on the header and I added this HTML code to the header.php

```
<!-- This is my extra div element-->    
<div class="extra-top"> <?php echo ' <a class="extra-topie" href="tel:6172010333">Call Us Now: (617) 201-0333</a> '; ?></div>
<!-- Ends extra div element-->
```

But the Anchor text is not working: it's not clickable yet.

Comment: Why are you using PHP for this? It appears to just be static. You should be able to just add the `<a>` straight into the HTML.

Comment: I did that but still not clickable, do you mean like this:<!-- This is my extra div element--> 
  <a class="extra-topie" href="tel:6172010333">Call Us Now: (617) 201-0333</a> 
   <!-- Ends extra div element-->

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Could you elaborate on "not clickable"? Does it show the hand thing? If not, inspect the element with your browser's dev tools to make sure there is nothing on top of it.

Comment: It does not appear as a regular anchor text with a hyperlink , I'll try that though

Answer (score 0):

For me work... But why you insert PHP echo if not use no variable?

Try this:

```
<!-- This is my extra div element-->
<div class="extra-top"><a class="extra-topie" href="tel:6172010333">Call Us Now: (617) 201-0333</a></div>
<!-- Ends extra div element-->
```

Comment: Still not working :D Perhaps there;s some php code that I need to add since I am adding the HMTL in the header.php file

Comment: @DaveBud it is possible. make sure it's not under an `if` statement that is preventing it from showing. But you said it appears on the page it just doesn't click , right?

Answer (score 0):

This suppose to work both the PHP and Direct HTML if you place it the right place.
If it is still not clickable, that mean you have issue with associated Application to handle dialer in Windows.. try from mobile and it should show its working.
Just tried that on my WordPress, it didn't work in desktop because I don't have default phone dialer ..but worked from mobile.